# Use a specific SSH for a repository. sshCommand - fatal: bad config line in file ./config

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to configure a specific repository to use a specific SSH by add `sshCommand` property to `REPOSITY_FOLDER/.git/config` file

[image]

But can't make it work.

What do I do wrong?

p.s. on Windows

Comment: No screen dumps please.  You should instead copy and paste the contents of the file, and the error message, into your question as text.  You can/should use the `{}` button in the editor's toolbar, or just indent everything at least 4 spaces, to have the text be formatted as code.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my point. My comment to you has nothing to do with your specific question. Rather, it is Stack Overflow policy that any part of the question that is important to understanding the question MUST be represented as searchable, editable text in the content of the question itself.  There are reasons why images uploaded for other purposes are also bad. Please review this document to understand all the reasons that you should not include images in your question: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Allright.  I give up.  If you can't understand "Stack Overflow doesn't want images in their questions", I don't know what more I can say.  I do see that there is information in the image that isn't in your question, and in fact, the whole point of the question came down to a syntax problem in text you only show in the image, so I don't get what you're arguing about either.  But OK, whatever.

Comment: ***"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*** - As you say, the image isn't important to the question, so then it isn't there to ***"illustrate a problem that can't be made clear in any other way"***, and so it doesn't belong there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Had to change `\` to `/` in the path of SSH

Comment: Had to change \\ to / where?

Comment: What SSH...I don't see any SSH...oh, in the IMAGE?  You said "information from the image is not that important", but it is actually Critically Important, as the problem addressed by the question resided in text only made available to the reader via that image.  Your answer is meaningless unless the user is able to refer to the image.  With that being the case, it is absolutely clear that the info in the image should be in the question as plain text.  Please take a fresh look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question.